# C++ tokenization

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, tokenize, lexer

I am writing a lexer in C++  and I am reading from a file character by character, however, how do you do tokenization in this case? I can't use strtok since  I have character not a string. Somehow I need to keep reading until I reach a delimeter?

Comment: why aren't you using Lex + Yacc (Bison)?

Comment: I used JavaCC but I am handcrafting one now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**. You need to keep reading until you hit a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions.

The simplest thing to do is exactly that: keep a buffer (`std::string`) of the characters you already read until you reach a delimiter. At that point, you build a token from the accumulated characters in the buffer, clear the buffer, and push the delimiter (if necessary) in the buffer.

Another solution would be to read ahead of the time: ie, pick up the entire line with `std::getline` (for example), and then check what's on this line. In general the end-of-line is a natural token delimiter.

This works well... when delimiters are easy.

Unfortunately some languages, like C++, have awkward grammars. For example, in C++ `>>` can be either:

- the operator `>>` (for right-shift and stream extraction)
- the end of two nested templates (ie could be rewritten as `> >`)

In those cases... well, just don't bother with the difference in the tokenizer, and let your AST building pass disambiguate, it's got more information.

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of information provided you.
If you want to read upto a delimiter from a File, use getline(char *,int,char) function.

getline() is use to read upto n characters or upto a delimiter.

Example:

```
 #include<fstream.h>
using namespace std;

    main()
    {
        fstream f;

        f.open("test.cpp",ios::in);
        char *c;
        f.getline(c,2,' ');
        cout<<c; // upto 1 char or till a space 

    }
```

Comment: Typically in tokenization there are multiple delimiters, for example all forms of whitespace (16 different unicode code points) can be considered delimiters. Delimiters can also be contextual: when parsing an identifier (say `\w+`) any character matching `\W` is a delimiter: allowing `2+3` to be parsed as 3 tokens.